# Will android studio run on 1366 x 768 pixel laptop?

Tags: android-studio, configuration

I am going to buy a laptop only for android studio. But I did not find any laptops with resolution 1200x800. But found more bigger screen laptops and they are very costly. So should I go for 1366x768 pixel laptop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of-course android studio works fine with it. and Resolution does not matter for android studio. Your laptop configuration matters, i.e processor and RAM mainly.
below link for download android studio also system configuration according to OS.
**[DOWNLOAD ANDROID STUDIO AND SPECIFICATION DETAILS](https://developer.android.com/studio/?gclid=Cj0KCQiApvbhBRDXARIsALnNoK3V_A8LALpIsD8Y9l-wfMlSEYmr7MJUVgUZUGsfDVgzf2V3rL1dZsYaAnb7EALw_wcB#downloads)**